# Can't get back from browser to app

Tags: android, api, github, authorization

I am trying to authorize my GitHub app and turn back to my app. I open authorization page with Intent but can't go back to my app from browser. Could you please look at my code and tell me where I got it wrong?

LoginActivity.java

```
private final String clientId="myclientid";
private final String clientSecret="myclientsecret";
private final String redirectUri="http://localhost";
private final String state="randomshit";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?" +
                            "&client_id="+clientId+
                           "&redirect_uri="+redirectUri+
                            "&state="+state)
                    );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // the intent filter defined in AndroidManifest will handle the return from ACTION_VIEW intent
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(redirectUri)) {
        String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");

        if (code != null) {
            Log.d("code",code);
        }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.figengungor.retrogithub">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="localhost"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My GitHub app and redirect uri:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `can't go back to my app from browser`? What is the response you are getting?

Comment: what happens when you press 'back button' in the phone?

Comment: After authorization, it redirects to my redirectUri and code parameter is appended to my redirectUri which means authorization is successful. It is said that if redirectUri matches with my redirect in the intent filter I added it should go back to app and then my onResume part extract the code parameter. Isn't it supposed to work that way?

Comment: when the button is clicked, first the URL will be generated. The URL is: "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?" + "&client_id="+clientId+ "&redirect_uri="+redirectUri+ "&state="+state;

Then since you said startActivity(intent) with Intent. VIEW; it will open the browser and goto the above said URL.

That is it. After that there is nothing in the code to do.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're using "http" and "localhost" for the intent filter?
I think your problem is that the browser will always handle the redirect since it understands the protocol (http).
I would use a different protocol and hostname. For example:

```
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="consumecode"
                android:scheme="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Make sure you update the Authorization callback URL to "oauth://consumecode" on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

It simply done by use your own browser.
Means use **webview** for login in your app.its easy and i think it will solve your problem.

Comment: I know that alternative but I wanted to learn why it doesn't work with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `startActivityForResult(intent)` instead of `startActivity(intent)` in your loginButton onClick.